# Given a time-dependent function, complete it and find $c_0$

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, parity

1. Complete graphically and analytically the function $f(t)$ so that the coefficients of the exponential Fourier series are pure imaginary: $$f(t)=\begin{cases}2t+1&\text{if $0\leq t\leq2$},\\\underline{\phantom{2t+1}}&\text{if $\underline{\phantom{0}} <t<\underline{\phantom{2}}$},\end{cases}\quad\text{with $f(t)=f(t+\underline{\phantom{4}})$}.$$
2. Find analytically and graphically the value of the coefficient $c_0$ and indicate if the Fourier series has only odd frequencies except for the independent term of the series.

---

1. Let's sketch the graph of $f$:

   [image: First graph of f]

   If the coefficients of the exponential Fourier series are pure
   imaginary then $\Re(c_n)=0$, so $a_n=0$ and the function is odd.

   With this information we can extend the graph of $f$:

   [image: Complete function]

   We observe that
   $$\begin{cases}f(2)=5\\f(4)=9\end{cases}\equiv\begin{cases}2a+b=5\\4a+b=9\end{cases}\implies
   a=2,b=1,$$ so $f(t)=2t+1$ for $t\in[2,4]$ and so
   $$f(t)=\begin{cases}2t+1&\text{if $0\leq t\leq2$},\\2t+1&\text{if
   $2\leq t\leq4$}\end{cases}=2t+1\quad\text{with $f(t)=f(t+4)$},$$ the
   period is $T=4$ and $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.
2. $$c_0=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf(t)\,\mathrm
   dt=\frac14\int_0^4(2t+1)\,\mathrm dt=5.$$ Graphically:

   [image: Graph of the coefficient c0]

My question is: **how to know if the Fourier series has or not only odd frequencies except for the independent term of the series?**

We know that the Fourier series has only odd frequencies because $f$ is an odd function, but I am puzzled by the phrase "except for the independent term of the series" (which I know is $c_0=5$, but $5$ is an odd number!, so the answer would be... *no?*).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every constant function is even by definition, since $f(x)=f(-x)=c,$ for any constant $c.$

Comment: That is true, but I do not understand the help, since we can't define any constant function for $x\in(-2,0)$ to make $f$ odd.

Comment: @manooooh I was replying to the summary of your question (see last two paragraphs above), where you confused $5$ being an odd *number* with its being an **even** *function.*