# Why "is $f(x)$ an odd function?" does not work with this function?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

We know that $f(x)$ is odd if $-f(x)=f(-x)$. The function is $$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x-1&\text{if $-2<x<0$},\\2x+1&\text{if $0\leq x\leq2$}.\end{cases}$$

[image: Plot of f]

[(link)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Piecewise%5B%7B%7B2x-1,-2%3Cx%3C0%7D,%7B2x%2B1,0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D2%7D%7D%5D)

Now I want to know if $f$ is odd, so I query to WA [is `Piecewise[{{2x-1,-2<x<0},{2x+1,0<=x<=2}}]` an odd function?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+Piecewise%5B%7B%7B2x-1,-2%3Cx%3C0%7D,%7B2x%2B1,0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D2%7D%7D%5D+an+odd+function%3F):

[image: Question to WA]

I get the answer:

[image: Answer]

Now, if we query [plot `-Piecewise[{{2x-1,-2<x<0},{2x+1,0<=x<=2}}]` from `-2` to `2`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-Piecewise%5B%7B%7B2x-1,-2%3Cx%3C0%7D,%7B2x%2B1,0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D2%7D%7D%5D+from+-2+to+2) then we see the graph of $-f(x)$:

[image: Sketch of -f(x)]

If we query [plot `Piecewise[{{2(-x)-1,-2<-x<0},{2(-x)+1,0<=-x<=2}}]` from `-2` to `2`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Piecewise%5B%7B%7B2(-x)-1,-2%3C-x%3C0%7D,%7B2(-x)%2B1,0%3C%3D-x%3C%3D2%7D%7D%5D+from+-2+to+2) then we obtain $f(-x)$:

[image: Sketch of f(-x)]

As the plots are the same, then $-f(x)=f(-x)$, so the function is odd.

However in the first input, WA did not recognize that. Why?

Comment: $f(0)=1{{{}}}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown that is true, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, $f(0)=1 \ne -f(-0)$. Also, the domain you have specified for $f$ includes $2$ but not $-2$. Mathematica's Piecewise functions [have zero as a default value](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) (you can actually see this in your first plot), and so your function has $f(-2)=0$ but $f(2)=5$.

Repeating your query with [strict inequalities everywhere](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20Piecewise%5B%7B%7B2x-1,-2%3Cx%3C0%7D,%7B2x%2B1,0%3Cx%3C2%7D%7D%5D%20an%20odd%20function%3F) gives a function which Wolfram correctly says is odd.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. However, this question comes from [this other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3225017/525384), where the given function **includes** the $=$ to a part of the piecewise function, so I guess we need to find another expression instead of $2x-1$ to make it odd.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of *odd function* requires first that $-x$ be in the domain of the function whenever $x$ is. In your example, $2$ is in the domain but $-2$ is not, so it couldn't be odd. Also, for any odd function, it follows that $$f(-0)=f(0)=-f(0)\implies f(0)=0.$$ This, however, is not the case with your function. These are the two characteristics that prevent it from being odd.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. However, this question comes from [this other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3225017/525384), where the given function **includes** the $=$ to a part of the piecewise function, so I guess we need to find another expression instead of $2x-1$ to make it odd.